# How do I change the title of a webpage automatically for regular time intervals using JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, page-title

I have tried this:

```
for (i = 0; i < i+1; i++) {
    if (i%2 == 0) {
        document.title = "title1";
    } else {
        document.title = "title2";
    }
}
```

But due to the the continuous/never-ending for loop the browser (Google Chrome) hanged up. I'm a newbie in JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    changetitle()
}, 10000); // Every 10 seconds

function changetitle(){
    // Change title here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) function.

```
var isOdd = true;
setInterval(function(){
    document.title= isOdd ? "title1" : "title2";
    isOdd = !isOdd;
}, 100);
```

Something like this... The function passed to setInterval will be called asynchronously every 100 milliseconds. So your browser won't hang up.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use JavaScript timing events: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
   document.title = i++ % 2 == 0 ? "title1" : "title2";
}, 1000);
```

Every 1 second (1000 milliseconds) it will call this function and update the title.